# Input control needs to reflect the change based on the drop down selection in angular 4

Tags: angular

I am trying to update the value of input control based on the drop down changed event. I am not sure how to update the value in the input control as the html and components are in parent and child level. I have tried to write methods to retrieve the value but not sure where to filter the value and update the input control

The parent component has property defined called  fedExciseExpensesInputs. This retrieves all the values for that input control from the database.

```
export interface FedExciseExpense  {

        coveragePolicyTypeId: number;
        is953D: number;
        value?: number;
    }

  get fedExciseExpensesInputs(): Array<BackendDto.FedExciseExpense> {
    return  this.editableLob.fedExciseExpenses.map(x => {
      return x;
    });
  }
```

The change event is as follows

```
 coveragePolicyTypeChanged($event) {
    this.updateCedingComission(this.showCededComission && this.editableLob.isCededCommision);

    this._refProxy.getDefaultLineOfBusinessInputForClient(this.domicileId, this.industryId,this.selectedLineOfBusiness.id)
      .uiSignal('lineofbusinessDefault').subscribe(ret => {
          this.lob.fedExciseExpenses = ret.data.fedExciseExpenses;
    });
  }
```

In the parent component html , i am passing the value in child components selector. You will also notice  coveragePolicyTypeChanged called in the html

For e.g you can see below

[(fedExciseExpensesInputs)]="fedExciseExpensesInputs"

```
<incremental-captive-expenses [show]="show" *ngIf="incrementalExpensesInputs" [(incrementalExpensesInputs)]="incrementalExpensesInputs"
      [(fedExciseExpensesInputs)]="fedExciseExpensesInputs"  [currentSelectedCurrency]="currentSelectedCurrency" (isValid)="incrementalExpensesValid($event)">
</incremental-captive-expenses>


 <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 mb-3 highlighted">
        <label class="col-form-label">{{'CAPTIVES.LINES.POLICYTYPE.COVERAGETYPE.TITLE'|translate}}</label>
        <div class="only-ie">
          <select class="select-wrapper" [(ngModel)]="editableLob.coveragePolicyTypeId" (change)="coveragePolicyTypeChanged($event)"
            name="policyType" required tooltip="{{'CAPTIVES.LINES.POLICYTYPE.COVERAGETYPE.TITLETOOLTIP'|uppercase|translate}}"
            placement="bottom">
            <option disabled="disabled" [ngValue]="defaultPolicyType">{{'CAPTIVES.LINES.POLICYTYPE.COVERAGETYPE.SELECT'|translate}}</option>
            <option class="theme--option--default" *ngFor="let policyType of policyTypes" [ngValue]="policyType.id">{{'CAPTIVES.LINES.POLICYTYPE.COVERAGETYPE.'+policyType.name|uppercase|translate}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
```

The child component has a property defined which reads the input values like below. I need to change the assignment of 1 to be dynamic based on what the user has selected.

```
export class IncrementalCaptiveAssumptionsComponent extends Base.DynamicFormComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() incrementalExpensesInputs: Array<BackendDto.IncrementalExpense>;
  @Input() fedExciseExpensesInputs: Array<BackendDto.FedExciseExpense>;

    get fedExTax(): BackendDto.FedExciseExpense {
          return this.fedExciseExpensesInputs.find(x=> x.coveragePolicyTypeId == 1);
      }
}
```

The html of the parent component is as follows

```
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 mb-3">         
  <label class="col-form-label">{{'CAPTIVES.LINES.INCCAPTIVEEXPENSE.' + FedExciseKey|uppercase|translate}}</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm"  [(ngModel)]="fedExTax.value"
        [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
          name="{{FedExciseKey}}"
           numberFormat="numberPercent:.0-2"
          (ngModelChange)="change()"
          [required]="true"
          tooltip="{{'CAPTIVES.LINES.INCCAPTIVEEXPENSE.' + FedExciseKey + 'TOOLTIP'|uppercase|translate}}" placement="bottom">
        <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefer giving input data to child using

`<child-component [fedExciseExpensesInputs]="fedExciseExpensesInputs"]></child-component>`

And on dropdown change function in child use output function:

`<child-component (onChangeOutputFunctionInChild)="onChangeFunctionInParent></child-component>`

So use it like:

`<child-component [fedExciseExpensesInputs]="fedExciseExpensesInputs"] (onChildChange)="onChangeFunctionInParent></child-component>`

In child component ts use:
 @Output() onChildChange= new EventEmitter();

```
onDropDownChange(){
this.onChildChange.emit(yourData);
}
```

And get the data in onChangeFunctionInParent(value) function in parent ts.

Comment: Hello Prachi. I am bit confused. Isn't my current code too passing input value to child component via the child selector in the parent components HTML. Also how would we determine the selected value of drop down . I don't see any filter applied in your code . Shouldn't the filter be applied at the parent component level and pass the filtered value to the child

Comment: You can add on onDropDownChange(value) method in your dropdown in child component, in which selected value will be there. Then you can emit that value to the parent method and filter your input data list by that.